# What subset constraint means in the UML class diagram

Tags: class, uml

There is `subset` between Department class and person class but I don't know what does than mean?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Homerwork per chance...?

Look at the two relationships linked by the subset constraint:

- Each Department has many members
- Each Department has one manager

The subset expresses a constraint between those two.  If the elements of the latter relationship are a subset of the first, then how would you describe the implication?

**EDIT**

In response to your comment:

Without the constraint, a Person can be a member of a Department and manage any Department.  There's nothing that says whether they have to be a member of the department they manage.  That's what the constraint says: a manager must be a member of the department they manage.

> I think I will describe it by inheritance. right ?

Depends what you mean by inheritance.  Subtyping perhaps (at least analogously) but not implementation inheritance.  It's probably not how I'd prefer to describe it.  It is properly a subset: you'd be better describing why one is a subset of the other and what the implications are.

hth.

Comment: thanks @sfinnie . Is it only refers that the manager is a subset of the other members ?
I think I will describe it by inheritance. right ?